# How to add a member to a telegram group using the API

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api

When we're going to create a group, we can select (from the contact list) who we want to add to that group. How can I do the same (bulk add members) using a script (with the Telegram API or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried Python + [Telethon](http://Telethon)?

Well explained tutorial with setup and coding part. If you want to bulk add members - Telethon supports import from CSV file.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out, didn't know about this telethon

Comment: Sure. Happy to help. If this answered your issue- don't forget to mark my answer as "Answered". :)